# Compiling R from source doesn't find PCRE even if already installed

Tags: r, macos, macos-ventura

On macOS 13.4.1 (Ventura), I'm trying to compile R from source, but it doesn't find `pcre2.h` even if I have installed it:

```bash
cd /tmp
export R_VERSION=4.2.3

curl -O https://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-4/R-${R_VERSION}.tar.gz
tar -xzvf R-${R_VERSION}.tar.gz
cd R-${R_VERSION}

./configure  --prefix=/opt/R/${R_VERSION} \
    --enable-R-shlib \
    --enable-memory-profiling
```

```
R is now configured for aarch64-apple-darwin22.5.0

  Source directory:            .
  Installation directory:      /opt/R/4.2.3

  C compiler:                  gcc  -g -O2
  Fortran fixed-form compiler: gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -O2

  Default C++ compiler:        g++ -std=gnu++14  -g -O2
  C++11 compiler:              g++ -std=gnu++11  -g -O2
  C++14 compiler:              g++ -std=gnu++14  -g -O2
  C++17 compiler:              g++ -std=gnu++17  -g -O2
  C++20 compiler:              g++ -std=gnu++20  -g -O2
  Fortran free-form compiler:  gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -g -O2
  Obj-C compiler:              gcc -g -O2 -fobjc-exceptions

  Interfaces supported:        X11, aqua, tcltk
  External libraries:          pcre2, readline, curl
  Additional capabilities:     NLS, ICU
  Options enabled:             shared R library, shared BLAS, R profiling, memory profiling

  Capabilities skipped:        PNG, JPEG, TIFF, cairo
  Options not enabled:         

  Recommended packages:        yes
```

Then

```
sudo make
```

Fails because :

```
grep.c:73:10: fatal error: 'pcre2.h' file not found
# include<pcre2.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [grep.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [R] Error 2
make[1]: *** [R] Error 1
make: *** [R] Error 1
```

`pcre2` have been installed, using homebrew :

```
brew install pcre2
Warning: pcre2 10.42 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 10.42, run:
  brew reinstall pcre2
```

I can find the `pcre2.h` here:

```
ls /opt/homebrew/include | grep pcre
pcre2.h
pcre2posix.h
```

How do I tell R to use /opt/homebrew/include for `pcre2.h`?

Comment: You might be using the Apple Clang compiler that’s shipping with Xcode, rather than the clang/GCC installed via Homebrew, so it’s searching different include paths. Can you check that? (By default, `g++` is an alias for `clang++`, etc.)

Comment: `which clang` returns `/usr/bin/clang`, should it point to `/opt/hombrew` instead ?

Comment: Yes, it probably needs to. I’m no longer using Homebrew but I think you can use `brew link clang` to override the default clang installation. Alternatively, you can explicitly set the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables  before invoking `make`, but that’s more brittle. — Oh, and: don’t use `sudo make`, it messes up file permissions. `make` works, you only need `sudo make install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at that file it has a few `#define` statements around it:

```
#ifdef HAVE_PCRE2
  /* PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH is defined to 8 via config.h */
# include<pcre2.h>
#else
  /*
  Some systems might have pcre headers in a subdirectory -- not seen recently.
  */
# ifdef HAVE_PCRE_PCRE_H
#  include <pcre/pcre.h>
# else
#  include <pcre.h>
# endif
#endif
```

And pcre is funny because there is the newer pcre2 and the older (!!) pcre3. I suggest you a) check what `configure` produced, specifically in `config.h`.  And maybe b) check the current source version 4.3.1 as well as the current dev version.  Lastly, Kurt is quite masterful in his use of `autoconf` and `m4` so you can trace the detection code.

For what it is worth, in the 25+ years I looked after Debian's builds of R (plus some initially helping the then-maintainer) I have not had issues.

PS Also note that `./configure` hass two flags for pcre you could consider.  Worst case you can turn `pcre2` off:

```
  --with-pcre2            use PCRE2 library (if available) [yes] 
  --with-pcre1            use PCRE1 library (if available and PCRE2 is not)
                          [yes]
```

where `pcre1` is probably ancient.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up compiling without pcre on my mac as I wasn't finding a solution to this :)

Comment: Good to hear you are covered but it may be worth carrying this over to the r-sig-mac list to have other macheads look at it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of doing that, thanks a lot for the suggestion!